# .NET "Request.Files" capture extra input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I made a dynamically multi upload form with file type inputs. When you select a file new file input will appear. When submit the form all inputs captured by "Request.Files" at code behind.

There is no problem when i generate those file in a .aspx file but when i use Web User Control (.ascx) page "Request.Files" add 1 more request (for the blank file input).

Why ascx count the balnk input?

I share the codes below:

MultiImage.ascx

```
<ul id="imagesToUpload">
    <li><input type="file" class="imageToUpload" runat="server" /></li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.imageToUpload').live('change', function () {
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="imageInfoContainer"><span>Yüklenen görsel: ' + $(this).val() + ' </span><div class="deleteImage">Sil<div><div>');
    if ($('input:file').length < <%= MaxImageNumber %>) {
        $(this).parent().parent().append('<li><input type="file" class="imageToUpload" runat="server" /></li>');
        }
    });

    $('.deleteImage').live('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        if ($('input:file').length < 1) {
            $('#imagesToUpload').html('<li><input type="file" class="imageToUpload" runat="server" /></li>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

MultiImage.ascx.cs

```
var imageCollection = Request.Files; //Counts all file inputs included the blank one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Why ascx count the balnk input?

You mean why does `HttpRequest` object count that input? Because it is present in the request. You can however easily check if it is empty or not by looking at the `HttpPostedFile.ContentLength` property of each element inside Files collection.

Comment: Exactly! I did the same thing to prevent. But I am curious about why don't HttpRequest count that input at a web form pages (.aspx). What is the difference?

Comment: @pilavust I can't imagine there would be any difference between contents of the `Files` collection when called from within aspx or ascx code. The request object instance would be the same inside page and control, since it is simply `HttpContext.Current.Request`. Do you have some code that illustrates `Files` collection containing only non-empty inputs?

Comment: you are right. I missed a point. I used `HttpRequest` at aspx with page control. Sorry to bother.